# Apache downloads PHP files instead of displaying in browser when called via CMD (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, apache, apache2, sublimetext3

I've installed LAMP on my Ubuntu laptop with no apparent problems and successfully did the phpinfo() test by navigating to the file through the browser. But the same file is downloaded instead of executing when I'm trying to build from Sublime Text 3 using the following script:

```
 {  "cmd": ["/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" ,"$file"] }
```

That  worked the first couple of times I tested it, but stopped right after I changed the name of the build system and hasn't been functioning since even after I reversed the change. How would I go about fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$file` is "[The full path to the current file, e.g., C:\Files\Chapter1.txt.](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html)".

Apache isn't causing the file to be downloaded; you aren't requesting it from Apache.

You need to translate `$file` into a URL on your HTTP server.

Comment: The file is in the folder that I've set as the root directory for Apache in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. I've also tried "localhost/$filename" instead of "$file" but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's "$file_name" and not "$filename". Thanks for pointing me towards the wiki.